# Check if string is already printed

Tags: c, string

I am trying to build a C program that reads contents from a file, tokenize the contents and categorize the tokens at the same time, copying the tokens into an array of temp.My goal is to print the tokens that are not previously printed. In other words if the token has been already printed, skip this token from printing. My way to achieve this is to create a function that checks if the token has appeared in my array temp. If the token appeared in the array temp, then return 1 else return -1. My problem is, the function does not work, isAdded is always not 1. Thus, it still prints the previously printed tokens. I traced my code, and it seems correct to me. I don't know why it always return -1.

Here is my code:

```
char *temp[MAX]; /*globally declared*/


void tokenize(FILE *input){

char *token;
int k=0;

char word[1000];
while(!feof(input)){
    fgets(word,1000,input);
    token = strtok(word, " \t\n");
        while(token!=NULL){                     
            if(isAdded(token)!=1){
                if(isKeyword(token)==1){
                    printf("%s, %s\n", token, token);
                }
                temp[k] = (char*)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
                strcpy(temp[k],token);
                k++;
            }
            token= strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
}
}


int isAdded(char *token){
        int i=0;
        while(temp[i]!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(temp[i],token)==0){
                return 1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
            return -1;
        }
}


int isKeyword(char *token){
    int i=0;
        while(resWord[i]!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(resWord[i],token)==0){
                return 1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: What problem are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the last `return` outside the `while` loop.

Comment: probably better to give a bit more details, now that he removed `return -1` out of the loop, and altogether ;)

Comment: You gave me an idea. I used flag instead of directly returning a value. Thank you. Your answer somehow helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Tip: When a function executes a `return` statement, it terminates at this point and does not execute any other lines of this function!!!

---

Here is the problem:

```
while(temp[i]!=NULL){
  if(strcmp(temp[i],token)==0){
    return 1;
    break;
  }
  i++;
  return -1;
}
```

Explain to yourself what this code does:

1. Ready to check first word,
2. While temp has more words,
3. check it the token is the first word,
4. if yes, return 1 and break,
5. else, increase `i` to check second word,
6. return -1 (BEFORE CHECKING OTHER WORDS)!!!!!!

---

So, I would modify the functions as such:

```
int isAdded(char *token){
  int i=0; // begin from the start
  while(temp[i] != NULL) { // while temp has more words
    if(strcmp(temp[i],token) == 0) { // is token same as current word?
      return 1;  // yes return 1 (the functions TERMINATES here, break is not needed after that)
    }
    i++; // token was not the current word, increment counter by one
  }
  // if we reach this point, it means that we didn't find token inside temp[],
  // so return -1 (not found)
  return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int isAdded(char *token){
    int i=0, flag=0;
    while(temp[i]!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp[i],token)==0){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(flag==1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

I found the solution, since your answers somehow helped me. Thank you. I used a flag instead of directly returning a value.

Comment: It's ok that way Adrian, however you can avoid using an extra variable (i.e. a flag) as my answer indicates. Moreover, it's nice to accept an answer already made by the other users (if you like pmg's  answer accept that one) and don't post an almost same answer as the existed ones.

Comment: Stack overflow says, i can accept answers after 2 days :(

Comment: Stackoverflow says that you can accept your ***OWN*** answer after two days. You can accept any other answer now, just like you did, bravo! +1 to your question for that.